# django restframework try using djoser to create multiple model get unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

Im new to django rest-framework and Djoser and learning, trying to create a user with profile using UserCreateSerializer in Djoser.

I followed bunch of tutorials to create a Serializer with two models and when trying to create a user in browser api end with: get unexpected keyword argument in the template, i know what the error means but i dont know how
should i implement it or what did i do wrong.
here is my model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class User(AbstractUser):
    account_Option = (
        ('P', 'is_something'),
        ('L', 'is_somethingelse'),
    )
    ac_type = models.CharField(_("Status"),
                               max_length=1,
                               choices=account_Option,
                               default='P',
                               help_text=_('account Option'))


class MyClass(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)

    my_field = models.CharField(help_text=_('Enter your...'),
                                max_length=10,
                                unique=True,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True, )
```

and serializers:

```
from djoser.serializers import UserSerializer as BaseUserSerializer, UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserCreateSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.conf import settings
from core.models import MyClass
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class MyClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
        fields = ['my_field']


class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):
    profile = MyClassSerializer()

    class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password', 'email',
                  'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        # User_model = self.User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        User_model = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        new_profile = self.profile.objects.create(
            user=User_model, **profile_data)
        return User_model


class UserSerializer(BaseUserSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email',
                  'first_name', 'last_name', ]
```

in setting, config djoser as follows:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING': False,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}
DJOSER = {
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'core.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        # 'current_user': 'core.serializers.UserSerializer',
    }
}
```

and when try to post in browser api i get:

```
TypeError at /api/v1/users/

User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'profile'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/
Django Version:     3.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'profile'
```

i searched for a solution, i didnt find one that help and try things that i dont think they are relevant to the issue, apparently it must be something simple that i miss so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your User model does not have a profile attribute.

Comment: profile is my second class that i want to add in UserCreateSerializer if i dont add the profile it complains about not using it in the fields how should i add the second class then?

Comment: In line `User_model = User.objects.create(**validated_data)`, you are also passing the `profile` variable to the User object, but User has no profile defined.

Comment: i did that earlier and now again i test   ` User_model = User.objects.create(id=validated_data['id'], email=validated_data['email'], username=validated_data['username'],
                                         password=validated_data['password'], first_name=validated_data['first_name'], last_name=validated_data['last_name'],)
` but still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

well, its been a while but i figured maybe sharing what i learned about it so helping other newcomers,
as mentioned i was trying to mix djoser and another model(profile) and although you can do this buy some modifications and changes in djoser after some searching and thinking this is not the way to do this.
Djoser is doing a job and done it very well and i shouldn't mix that with another task for handling the profiles too, so i separate the logic instead of altering djoser and it work just fine.

ps: about my problem using serializers with two model, common methods to create a Serializer with two models were working and for my case didnt work cuase i didnt change djoser properly...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).